# Metal Texture is not filterable

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal

I am trying to mipmap a texture contained in an MTLTexture object. This texture was loaded from an OpenCV Mat. I can run correctly run kernels on this texture so I know my import process is correct.

Unfortunately, the generate mipmaps function gives this rather opaque error. I get a similar error even if I change `temp` to be BGRA.

```
-[MTLDebugBlitCommandEncoder generateMipmapsForTexture:]:1074: 
failed assertion `tex(MTLPixelFormatR8Uint) is not filterable.'
```

```
// create an MTL Texture
{
    MTLTextureDescriptor * textureDescriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor

    texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatR8Uint
                                                   width:cols
                                                   height:rows
                                                   mipmapped:NO];
    textureDescriptor.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderRead;
    _mImgTex = [_mDevice newTextureWithDescriptor:textureDescriptor];
}

{
    MTLTextureDescriptor * textureDescriptor = [MTLTextureDescriptor

    texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatR8Uint
                                                   width:cols
                                                   height:rows
                                                   mipmapped:YES];
    textureDescriptor.mipmapLevelCount = 5;
    textureDescriptor.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderRead | MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;
    _mPyrTex = [_mDevice newTextureWithDescriptor:textureDescriptor];
}


// copy data to GPU
cv::Mat temp;
cv::cvtColor(image, temp, cv::COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, cols, rows);
const int bytesPerPixel = 1 * 1; // 1 uint * 1 channels
const int bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * cols;

[_mImgTex replaceRegion:region mipmapLevel:0 withBytes:temp.data bytesPerRow:bytesPerRow];

// try to mipmap
id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];
MTLOrigin origin = MTLOriginMake(0, 0, 0);
MTLSize size = MTLSizeMake(cols, rows, 1);
[blitEncoder copyFromTexture:_mImgTex sourceSlice:0 sourceLevel:0 sourceOrigin:origin sourceSize:size toTexture:_mPyrTex destinationSlice:0 destinationLevel:0 destinationOrigin:origin];
[blitEncoder generateMipmapsForTexture:_mPyrTex];
[blitEncoder endEncoding];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [generateMipmapsForTextures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder/1400748-generatemipmapsfortexture) says:

> Mipmap generation works only for textures with color-renderable and color-filterable pixel formats.

If you look at the "Pixel Format Capabilities" table [here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf), you can see that `R8Uint` does not support `Filter` nor is it colour renderable (`Color`).

Perhaps `R8Unorm` (`MTLPixelFormatR8Unorm`) will work well for your needs. Otherwise you might need to write your own mip generation code with compute (although I'm not sure if there's a use case for mipmaps with non filterable textures).